# Docker machine is active, but shown as aborted in Virtual Box

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker, docker-machine

I do not understand, what is going on with docker machine on Windows using docker toolbox.

The machine is listed as active, when I run

```
> docker-machine ls
```

But when I go to the Virtual Box and check the machine state, it is shown as `aborted`. I also can not run the machine directly from Virtual Box.

[image]

Comment: Did you try kill all the virtual Box processes first, then reboot it?

Comment: @Windsooon, yep, I did, no change.

Answer (score 0):

All `ACTIVE` means is that the current shell you're in is set to use that machine with your Docker client.

> The reason for the * is to tell you which machine you're currently connected to e.g. if you run docker ps which Docker engine will it talk to?

[How is a Docker Machine marked as active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211767/how-is-a-docker-machine-marked-as-active)

From the information we have, I can't tell you why it is set to running, could even be a bug. You should be able to just recreate a new VM and be back in a supported state.

Also, you may be interested in **Docker for Windows**. It provides a native experience without the need to use Docker Machine. You can still keep Docker Machine and run them side-by-side, although you shouldn't need to.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but I do not like it's "Hype-V" and "Windows 10 Only" requirement. Docker machine seems to be more compatible.

Comment: It's not a "Windows 10 only" requirement. Docker makes a "Docker for Mac" client, as well as native Docker for Linux. https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/ (Note: This is the original announcement. Both clients are no longer in beta)